# HighCharts range area plot not working when plot is inverted

Tags: highcharts

I have an area range plot that won't display correctly, event though the normally oriented plot works fine.

These two plots are identical, except the second one has `inverted: true` in the chart options.

https://daltonanalytics.com/sd2/rohmhaas/philadelphiaDev/charts-horizontal.html
https://daltonanalytics.com/sd2/rohmhaas/philadelphiaDev/charts.html

I've modeled the JSON that feeds the data after the example range area plot and that seems to be correct. Anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

This actually doesn't work in the HighCharts arearange example either.  Here's a jsFiddle of the stock example, but with `inverted: true`

```
see  http://jsfiddle.net/Tt485/
```

Comment: It looks like it may be a bug on HighCharts' end. Have you made a thread in their support forum?

Comment: I did.  It's here:  http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=27363

Comment: That forum doesn't get too much traffic, but it is monitired by the maintainers of highCharts, so maybe he'll weigh in.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually if you zoom in, You will see correct results.

Comment: Thanks @Learner - I hadn't noticed that.  I tried zooming in just a little at a time.  I had to zoom pretty deep for the 'switch' to happen and the chart to appear correct.

Comment: So what is wrong, because both your links seem to not working. Jsfiddle looks fine, so please explain.

Comment: I think that's how the bug got through.  The JSFidle looks fine, but actually the plot shown is incorrect.  Make <inverted: false;> and you'll see what i mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Torstein at HighCharts has implemented a fix to this bug that is in his GitHub repo:  https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/commit/905535d2c56d61d034eed84eccf50e3bb44e1911

And he's posted an example here:

```
see http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Tt485/2/
```

I tried his fix and it worked perfectly.

He's planning a maintenance release soon to post the fix.